# Pass array variable to and from a nested bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a main script (main.bash)

```
#!/bin/bash
var=10                 #Variable to pass to the nested script
./nested.bash $var     #Pass 'var' to the nested script, which outputs the 'list' array
echo $list             #echo the output of the nested script
```

The nested script (nested.bash) is:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 == 10 ] ; then    
    list=(10-10 20-01 30-03 40-01 50-05)
fi
export list
```

I used `export`, but it is not working. How can 'nested.bash' pass `list` array to 'main.bash'?  More generally, how can this be done?

Comment: You can only export variables to child processes, not the parent process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to source the script with `.`. This runs it in the current shell process instead of in a child process, which means the outer script can see the changes made by the nested script.

**main**

```
#!/bin/bash
var=10
. ./nested.bash "$var"
echo "${list[@]}"
```

**nested.bash**

```
if [ "$1" == 10 ]; then    
    list=(10 20 30 40 50)
fi
```

Notes:

- Executables should generally not have an extension. The caller doesn't need to know if the script is written in bash or python or is a compiled C program. Prefer `main` to `main.bash`.
- Sourced scripts, on the other hand, should have an extension since they need to be executed in a particular interpreter. Name the inner script `nested.bash`.
- Always quote variable expansions.
- Array expansion is `"${list[@]}"`. If you write `$list` you'll only get the first element.
- You don't have to pass `"$var"` in and reference it as `"$1"` in the nested script. You can reference `"$var"` directly if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can't export variables to a parent process. `export` is only used to pass variables to child processes. It's also not possible to export arrays.

The way to send data back to the parent process is through standard output, using command substitution.

`main.bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=10                 
list=($(./nested.bash "$var"))
echo "${list[@]}"
```

`nested.bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 == 10 ] ; then    
    list=(10 20 30 40 50)
fi
echo "${list[@]}"
```

Comment: It is a risky method to pass arrays like this. Bash has better ways to pass lists as `null` or ASCII FS `\37` delimited entries to be read-back with `mapfile -d '' list < <(nested.bash)` or `mapfile -d $'\37' list < <(nested.bash` having `nested.bash` do `printf %s\\0 "${list[@]}"` or `printf %s\\37 "${list[@]}"`. The ASCII FS method can also work with older bash having only `read -a` and no `mapfile`, as `read -a` cannot read `null` delimited entries all at once, since it uses the `IFS` variable for record separation.